# Removing Unnecessary Header Title in PHPBB such as "Index Page" or "View Topic"

Tags: php, seo, phpbb

I need help removing the unnecessary PHPBB header title on my forum for SEO purposes.

I need some type of hack or something to get this removed.

I want to have the title of a certain topic followed by a category and then the name of the forum.

THanks GUys!

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to do this is to find the template files for the style you have chosen and modify it to your liking. PHPBB uses a fairly straightforward templating language so this should be easy.